# Using Python dictionary, it is better to check the key presence or catch the exception?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've written a code that uses largely the Python dictionary for incrementing some counters (the number of counters is not fixed)

The common pattern is:

```
if not key in dictionary1:
    dictionary1[key] = init()
dictionary[key]["last_value"] += current_value
```

In order to speed up my code execution, it is better to write a try-catch clause instead of a conditional statement?

For instance,

```
try:
  dictionary[key]["last_value"] += current_value
except KeyError:
  dictionary[key] = init()
  dictionary[key]["last_value"] += current_value
```

Comment: Use `dict.get(key, default)`.

Comment: I need to store values, not get them.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dictionary = defaultdict(init)
dictionary[key]["last_value"] += current_value
```

If the `key` is not in the dictionary when it is looked up, it will be added, with the value given by `init()`.

Comment: Unless you know for sure that some part of your code is causing performance problems, then trying to fine-tune optimise it is a bad idea. The performance of both of your options and of this approach will probably be very similar, but this approach results in minimal code and is a very common way to implement exactly your situation

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `dictionary.get(key, default)` can be used here. As for the try-catch, use it for legitimate exception handling.

You may have to do it this way:

```
if dictionary.get(key, None) is None:
    dictionary[key] = init()

dictionary[key]["last_value"] += current_value
```

Answer (score 1):

The more pythonic way is: ask for foregiveness, not for permission. But as you can see, you would have to double code, which is also bad.

Luckyly, there's another solution:

```
dictionary.setdefault(key, init())["value"] += current_value
```

So, if `dictionary` does not contain `key`, `setdefault` will create it and assign the result of `init` to it. Then, you can assign your own value.

**NOTE:** As stated in the comments by L3viatan, this is not a good choice if `init()` is doing anything else than returning a value like manipulating a global variable or doing some very time intensive work, because `init()` will be called every time this line is executed. The returned value will just be ignored.

Comment: That depends on what `init()` is doing exactly, and how costly it is.

Comment: @L3viathan: What do you mean exactly? Shouldn't it do the same (logically, I don't know the exact implementation) as the OP's variant only in less self written code?

Comment: This fits for me, since the init is simply another dictionary, like: `{"last_x": 0, "last_y": 0, "last_z": 0}

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle No, because `init()` is _always_ executed in your version, it's just that the result of it is sometimes ignored.

Comment: @L3viathan: You're right, didn't think aboout that. If `init()` does anything else than just returning a value, it might be bad. I'll add a statement about that.